# Why JBoss create only one ActiveMQ consumer?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, message-driven-bean, jboss-eap-7, resource-adapter

Why `JBoss EAP 7` create only one consumer with `Active MQ`(not `Artemis`)? How to increase number of consumer?

I've tried:

- increase maxSession `ActivationConfigProperty`
- increase mdb pool size (via `bean-instance-pools` tag)
- set min/max pool size inside `connection-definition` tag

My configuration:

**mdb-pool configuration**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:5.0">
...
<mdb>
    <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="com.icl.amq.jmsra.rar"/>
    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
</mdb>
<pools>
    <bean-instance-pools>
        <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="5" instance-acquisition-timeout="10" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
        <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="40" instance-acquisition-timeout="10" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
    </bean-instance-pools>
</pools>
...
```

**resource-adapter configuration**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:5.0">
...
 <resource-adapter id="amq.jmsra.main">
    ...
     <connection-definitions>
         <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="${amq.jndi.factory}" enabled="true" pool-name="ConnectionFactory">
             <xa-pool>
                 <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                 <initial-pool-size>10</initial-pool-size>
                 <max-pool-size>35</max-pool-size>
             </xa-pool>
         </connection-definition>
     </connection-definitions>
 </resource-adapter>
...
```

**MDB code:**

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionFactoryLookup", propertyValue = "${amq.jndi.factory}"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "in_queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="minSessions", propertyValue="5"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="maxSessions", propertyValue="40")
})
@ResourceAdapter("amq.jmsra.main")
public class ServerMessageListener implements MessageListener {
...
```

I expect this configuration increase number of consumers, however when viewing the status of queues from `ActiveMQ` web console I see only 1 consumer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me, based on the source-code of the ActiveMQ JCA RA, that sessions will be created on demand up to `maxSessions` based on message throughput. Therefore, if you simply start MDB and there are no messages to be consumed then I would expect just 1 session to be active.

Try putting `Thread.sleep(5000);` in your MDB's `onMessage()` and then push a couple thousand messages into the queue where its listening. I bet you'll see the consumer count increase as the JCA RA is forced to create new sessions to keep up with demand.

Comment: Thank you for your response! But it did not help :( I add `@PostConstruct` method for my MDB and see that different threads initialize my MDB, but number of consumers still one. It seems like many sessions use one connection.